# expect redirect outputs giberish

Tags: bash, redirect, expect

I have  `backup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
expect backup.exp
```

and `backup.exp`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#exp_internal 1
#log_user 0
set timeout 29

puts "----------------- [exec date +%Y.%m.%d\ %H:%M:%S] ------ exp start -----"
spawn -noecho ssh andrej@10.11.22.17

expect {
  timeout { send_user "\n--- failed to get expected string---\n"; exit 1 }
  eof { send_user "\nSSH failure\n"; exit 1 }
  " andrej $ "
}    

send "sudo bash\r"
send "ls -lh\r"

send exit\r
send exit\r
interact

puts "----------------- [exec date +%Y.%m.%d\ %H:%M:%S] ------ exp ende ------"
```

when I run

```
bash backup.sh >> backup.templog 2>&1
```

I get

```
----------------- 2015.09.02 18:48:29 ------ exp start -----
Last login: Wed Sep  2 18:48:24 2015 from 10.11.22.16
^[]0;andrej@centos7c:~/andrej^G^[[?1034h^[[01;32mandrej@centos7c ^[[01;34m18:48 andrej $ ^[[00msudo bash
^[]0;root@centos7c:/home/andrej/andrej^G^[[?1034h^[[01;31mroot@centos7c ^[[01;34m18:48 andrej $ ^[[00mls -lh
total 16K
-rw-rw-r--. 1 andrej andrej 13K Jun 30 19:04 iptables.sh
drwxrwxr-x. 2 andrej andrej   6 Jun 17 22:46 ^[[0m^[[01;34mmount^[[0m
^[]0;root@centos7c:/home/andrej/andrej^G^[[01;31mroot@centos7c ^[[01;34m18:48 andrej $ ^[[00mexit
exit
^[]0;andrej@centos7c:~/andrej^G^[[01;32mandrej@centos7c ^[[01;34m18:48 andrej $ ^[[00mexit
logout
Connection to 10.11.22.17 closed.
----------------- 2015.09.02 18:48:39 ------ exp ende ------
```

but when I do

```
bash backup.sh
```

, I get nice output that I need :

```
----------------- 2015.09.02 18:52:09 ------ exp start -----
Last login: Wed Sep  2 18:48:39 2015 from 10.11.22.16
andrej@centos7c 18:52 andrej $ sudo bash
root@centos7c 18:52 andrej $ ls -lh
total 16K
-rw-rw-r--. 1 andrej andrej 13K Jun 30 19:04 iptables.sh
drwxrwxr-x. 2 andrej andrej   6 Jun 17 22:46 mount
root@centos7c 18:52 andrej $ exit
exit
andrej@centos7c 18:52 andrej $ exit
logout
Connection to 10.11.22.17 closed.
----------------- 2015.09.02 18:52:20 ------ exp ende ------
```

How can I get rid of extra giberish  when outputing to the log file when executing the script?   I am using centos 7.1 in both server and client.
If you have any sugesstion please help me out. Thank you very much.

Comment: Those are color and other escape codes. Your terminal is interpreting them so you don't see them. When run under expect that isn't happening correctly (something, possibly expect) is turning them into normal characters instead). Do you have `ls` aliased to `ls --color=always` or something like that? And what is in `PS1` on the remote host? Is it failing to check for an interactive session before adding color to the prompt?

Comment: I have `ls='ls --color=auto'`  and  `\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h \[\033[01;34m\]\A \W $ \[\033[00m\]`  How can I see if "Is it failing to check for an interactive session before adding color to the prompt"?

Comment: `--color=auto` shouldn't send color codes when it doesn't see a terminal attached. You have to look for something in the init scripts which checks for an interactive session. It might be looking at `$-` or at `$PS1`, etc. Which file the config is in also matters. `.bashrc` is used for interactive shells. `.bash_profile` is used for login shells (interactive or not). etc.

Comment: How can I chage the PS1 ? I tried `send "PS1=XLX\r" `  and `send "[exec set PS1 XLX]\r"` it is not working.

Comment: `set` to set variables is a `csh` thing. Try `send "PS1=XLX\r"`?.

Comment: @EtanReisner, using expect, you *should* get an interactive session. I'm somewhat fuzzy on the implementation, but the spawned process is attached to a pseudo-tty so that the program can interacted with it. Handling prompts is a PITA with expect.

Comment: @glennjackman I wasn't sure but suspected that was probably true as well. I'm unsure what would be mangling the escapes though.

Comment: It's the redirection that's bypassing the terminal.

Comment: before `send "PS1=XLX\r"` I get `^[]0;andrej@centos7c:~/andrej^G^[[01;32mandrej@centos7c ^[[01;34m21:17 andrej $ ^[[00msudo bash^M` and after : `^[]0;andrej@centos7c:~/andrej^GXLXsudo bash^M`. So it is better, yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rewriting a but to address a couple of issues:

- expect has 2 built-in methods to get the current datetime: `timestamp` (expect-specific) and `clock` (from Tcl)
- I turn off output (`log_user 0`)
- when it's important, I change the prompt and use an anchored regular expression to match it
- I only output the results of the `ls -lh` command, which I suspect is your goal.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#exp_internal 1
set timeout 29

proc separator {msg} {
    puts [format "----------------- %s ------ %s -----" [timestamp -format "%Y.%m.%d %T"] $msg]
}

separator "exp start"

log_user 0

spawn -noecho ssh andrej@10.11.22.17

expect {
  timeout { send_user "\n--- failed to get expected string---\n"; exit 1 }
  eof { send_user "\nSSH failure\n"; exit 1 }
  " $ "
}    

send "sudo bash\r"
expect " $ "

send "PS1='$'\r"
expect -re {\$$}

send "ls -lh\r"
expect -re {(.+)\r\n\$$}

puts $expect_out(1,string)

send "exit\r"
expect " $ "

send "exit\r"
expect eof

separator "exp ende"
```

Comment: I like how it works from `cron`, except that it outputs the: `ls -lh` twice, wich does not happen if I run it from command line. Way? But if I run it from command line, I get: `can't read "expect_out(1,string)": no such element in array while executing "puts $expect_out(1,string)" (file "backup.exp" line 30)` So I removed the line `puts $expect_out(1,string)` and it works in both ways. How come? It also seems to work fine without the line `expect -re {\$$}`. What is it purpose? Thanks